# check the version of downloaded webdriver programatically

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, webdriver-manager

I'm working on Selenium in C#. I had been using the webdriver manager to update the chrome and the firefox drivers.

```
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver("https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/chromedriver_win32.zip", 
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "chromedriver.exe"),
            "chromedriver.exe"
        );
```

but **this is downloading the driver** each time I **run the program**, I only want to **download the driver** even if it is not the **latest version** according to the browser's version.

**How will I check the downloaded version or existing version of the web-driver**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/38807/34209

Comment: i had tried this but when we call the  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("./"); it will initiate a new browser session, I am trying to update the drivers before the browser get initalized